# Uploading big files result on connection aborted

Tags: wordpress, cpanel, whm

I'm triying to upload a 2,4GB of files to a Wordpress site hosted on my server. I already increased a lot of `php.ini` resources limits, specifically:

```
upload_max_filesize = 7000M
post_max_size = 12000M
memory_limit = 4000M
max_execution_time = 6000
max_input_time = 3000
```

But when i try upload a 2.4Gb file i get the next error in the request: `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

My WHM&CPanel server have installed imunify360 with kernel care and PHP hardened enabled.

Answers:

@Jaromanda X - The `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` happens a second after upload starts, the indicador usually stops between 1.33% and 0.35%

@Nikita Kipriyanov - The logs does not specify any error, only warnings about imunify360 rules, but not blocking. The error happens when i try to upload a backup made with All-in-One WP Migration. and the ajax call is made to /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=ai1wm_import&ai1wm_import=1 endpoint.

@djdomi - The free versión of plugin only allow restore a backup uploading it as normal file and with .wpress extension, i can't compress or upload directly to the server due free versión doesn't support it. I can successfully upload the file to a folder through cpanel file manager, the problem only happen uploading in media library or import interface of plugin.

Comment: does `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` happen immediately, or after *some time*

Comment: Also, do web server logs mention anything about it? What web server is that? Attach anything relevant [into the question](https://serverfault.com/posts/1134399/edit). Also describe the particular circumstances on how you receive the error (e.g. try to invoke it with `curl` and post output). (Notice we can ask you do do some adjustments to web server configs, and that's your problem how you do these exact changes under the control panel.)

Comment: why not splitting the file in question and unpack it over the shell?

Comment: I already answer all the questions, please review and help me please.

Comment: No, I asked you to **copy-paste a relevant log into the question**, whether there are errors or not. Don't only describe what you see, show it to us. Which web server you are using and what is its configuration you didn't answered either; attach it too. Want help? Provide information. Expect also we ask for more when we began understanding what is going on and what else to know.

Comment: How exactly are you seeing this error? Computer screen turns blank with red letters? It says an error message through speakers? Describe this. The error you shown is not how normally web communication-related errors look, so I don't understand yet. Also, check *php* error logs, are they logged somewhere?